# アレなら and というなら in the same sentence

Tags: translation

Situation: B has asked A what she thinks of her clothes and A said 安心感がある。 (which makes little sense to me, but seems to be quite common when Japanese people talk about fashion). B's clothing is very recognizable, a fact noted by C. And then D comments:

> 昔からずっとアレなら安心感と言うのなら流石Aさんというところ・・・

Several things I don't quite understand:

1. Should there be a full stop after 昔からずっと? (it's a manga) Because it doesn't seem to fit into the rest of the sentence.
2. How do アレなら and 言うのなら play together?

My best guess about the translation is something like "If anyone would say about *that horrible outfit* that it gives off anshinkan, it would be A-san."

Comment: The passage is too broken and/or scrappy to make a safe guess... what has been previously said?

Comment: A says 安心感がある, then C says 確かに遠目で見ても一発でBさんってわかるもんな. And then follows the sentence mentioned above (after that, B is upset about C and D)

Comment: Hmm... okay.... then @l'électeur's answer seems quite probable, but I can't say that I can visualize the situation without knowing the relationship between them...

Comment: Just to add to the mental picture... What is B wearing?

Comment: Harajuku girl fashion - lots of frills and stuff.

Answer (score 3):

> 昔{むかし}からずっとアレなら安心感{あんしんかん}と言{い}うのなら流石{さすが}Aさんというところ・・・

＝

> 『昔からずっとアレなら安心感（がある）。』**と**（Aさんが）言うのなら、「流石Aさん！」**と**
>   （私は）いうところ・・・

This is an informally spoken "sentence", which is why it might be difficult to even parse it unless one actually speaks natural Japanese.  You would need to read between the lines, so to speak, as it is not the kind of sentence you would encounter in a textbook.  You would need to fill in the unmentioned words to translate.

> 1) Should there be a full stop after 昔からずっと? (it's a manga) Because it doesn't seem to fit into the rest of the sentence.

No, there should not.  Read on to find out how it fits into the rest of the sentence.

> 2) How do アレなら and 言うのなら play together?

「アレなら」 modifies 「安心感」 and 「言うのなら」 modifies 「流石Aさん」.  These function separately and the latter pair constitutes the core of the sentence itself while the former just constitutes the statement I quoted above with 『』.  Thus, the two conditionals can coexist within one sentence.

Finally, my own TL:

> If A says "It produces a sense of security if B has always been dressed like ***that***.", then I would have to say that A has wit.

Comment: Okay, that makes a little more sense. I still don't quite understand the アレなら, or more specifically the なら. For context, A and B have known each other since they were little. So in your translation "if B has always been dressed" sounds odd, because I would expect that A knows how B dresses. So can なら here also mean "because" - "it makes me feel safe that she always dresses like that"?

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't find that interpretation reasonable.
2. The writer probably wanted to express it's not sure if her clothes have been actually so, and failed to write 昔からずっとアレで安心感と言うなら (if they have always been *that* since the past and she still says "reliable"). (If you want to get rid of ambiguity, you can say …アレだとして、それで安心感と…)